# Installation Issue of 389DS Package on Centos Server

Tags: ldap

When I want to install the 389-ds Directory into my Linux CentOS Server I am having this issue. I tried to do solve a different way and as well tried to install missing Package but unable to solve the issue and it remains the same error.

### I run the Below Command:

yum install -y 389-ds openldap-clients

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Setting up Install Process
No package openldap-clients available.
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package 389-ds.noarch 0:1.2.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: 389-admin for package: 389-ds-1.2.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: 389-admin-console for package: 389-ds-1.2.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: 389-admin-console-doc for package: 389-ds-1.2.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: 389-console for package: 389-ds-1.2.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: 389-ds-base for package: 389-ds-1.2.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: 389-ds-console for package: 389-ds-1.2.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: 389-ds-console-doc for package: 389-ds-1.2.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: 389-dsgw for package: 389-ds-1.2.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: idm-console-framework for package: 389-ds-1.2.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package 389-admin.x86_64 0:1.1.35-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/repl-monitor.pl for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: 389-ds-base for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mod_nss for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: nss-tools for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(CGI) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DSCreate) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DSMigration) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DSUpdate) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DSUtil) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Dialog) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DialogManager) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(FileConn) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Inf) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Migration) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Mozilla::LDAP::API) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Mozilla::LDAP::Conn) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Mozilla::LDAP::LDIF) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Mozilla::LDAP::Utils) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Resource) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Setup) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SetupLog) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Mozilla-LDAP for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: policycoreutils-python for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libadminutil.so.0()(64bit) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libadmsslutil.so.0()(64bit) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package 389-admin-console.noarch 0:1.1.8-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package 389-admin-console-doc.noarch 0:1.1.8-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package 389-console.noarch 0:1.1.7-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: jpackage-utils for package: 389-console-1.1.7-1.el6.noarch
---> Package 389-ds.noarch 0:1.2.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: 389-ds-base for package: 389-ds-1.2.2-1.el6.noarch
---> Package 389-ds-console.noarch 0:1.2.6-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package 389-ds-console-doc.noarch 0:1.2.6-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package 389-dsgw.x86_64 0:1.1.11-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(CGI) for package: 389-dsgw-1.1.11-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Mozilla::LDAP::API) for package: 389-dsgw-1.1.11-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Mozilla::LDAP::Conn) for package: 389-dsgw-1.1.11-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Mozilla::LDAP::Utils) for package: 389-dsgw-1.1.11-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Mozilla-LDAP for package: 389-dsgw-1.1.11-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package idm-console-framework.noarch 0:1.1.7-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: jss >= 4.2 for package: idm-console-framework-1.1.7-2.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ldapjdk for package: idm-console-framework-1.1.7-2.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package 389-admin.x86_64 0:1.1.35-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/repl-monitor.pl for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: 389-ds-base for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mod_nss for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: nss-tools for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(CGI) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DSCreate) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DSMigration) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DSUpdate) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DSUtil) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Dialog) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DialogManager) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(FileConn) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Inf) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Migration) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Mozilla::LDAP::API) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Mozilla::LDAP::Conn) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Mozilla::LDAP::LDIF) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Mozilla::LDAP::Utils) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Resource) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Setup) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SetupLog) for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Mozilla-LDAP for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: policycoreutils-python for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package 389-adminutil.x86_64 0:1.1.19-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package 389-console.noarch 0:1.1.7-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: jpackage-utils for package: 389-console-1.1.7-1.el6.noarch
---> Package 389-ds.noarch 0:1.2.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: 389-ds-base for package: 389-ds-1.2.2-1.el6.noarch
---> Package 389-dsgw.x86_64 0:1.1.11-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(CGI) for package: 389-dsgw-1.1.11-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Mozilla::LDAP::API) for package: 389-dsgw-1.1.11-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Mozilla::LDAP::Conn) for package: 389-dsgw-1.1.11-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Mozilla::LDAP::Utils) for package: 389-dsgw-1.1.11-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Mozilla-LDAP for package: 389-dsgw-1.1.11-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package idm-console-framework.noarch 0:1.1.7-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: jss >= 4.2 for package: idm-console-framework-1.1.7-2.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ldapjdk for package: idm-console-framework-1.1.7-2.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/repl-monitor.pl for package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64

>......
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(Setup)
Error: Package: 389-dsgw-1.1.11-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(CGI)
Error: Package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: mod_nss
Error: Package: 389-dsgw-1.1.11-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(Mozilla::LDAP::API)
Error: Package: 389-dsgw-1.1.11-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(Mozilla::LDAP::Utils)
Error: Package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(DSUpdate)
Error: Package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(Inf)
Error: Package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(Dialog)
Error: Package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(CGI)
Error: Package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(DSCreate)
Error: Package: 389-console-1.1.7-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: jpackage-utils
Error: Package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: /usr/bin/repl-monitor.pl
Error: Package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(Mozilla::LDAP::Conn)
Error: Package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl-Mozilla-LDAP
Error: Package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(SetupLog)
Error: Package: idm-console-framework-1.1.7-2.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: jss >= 4.2
Error: Package: idm-console-framework-1.1.7-2.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: ldapjdk
Error: Package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: 389-ds-base
Error: Package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(DSMigration)
Error: Package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(Mozilla::LDAP::LDIF)
Error: Package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(Resource)
Error: Package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(Migration)
Error: Package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: policycoreutils-python
Error: Package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(Mozilla::LDAP::Utils)
Error: Package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(DSUtil)
Error: Package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(DialogManager)
Error: Package: 389-dsgw-1.1.11-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(Mozilla::LDAP::Conn)
Error: Package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(FileConn)
Error: Package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(Mozilla::LDAP::API)
Error: Package: 389-ds-1.2.2-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: 389-ds-base
Error: Package: 389-admin-1.1.35-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: nss-tools
Error: Package: 389-dsgw-1.1.11-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl-Mozilla-LDAP
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

It will be great appreciated to you.

Comment: Ensure epel repo is installed (`yum install epel-release` or install the [rpm](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm)), then start with `yum install --enablerepo=epel 389-ds-base`. If you still have errors for `mod_nss`, `jss`, `ldapjdk`, `nss-tools` install them manually first. See https://directory.fedoraproject.org/docs/389ds/download.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did everything before and as well I followed the URL which one you give me. Whenever I am trying to install the package of 398-ds. I think there is missing some dependencies of EPEL. I tried to install manually I mean Download the rpm Package and Install but same error I am getting. I am using EPEL Redhat.